# Metadate file could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

After I attempted to download a Visual Studio solution from Team Foundation Server, I get multiple errors complaining about 'unfound metadata files'. I have already tried toggling the checkbox in configuration property.

Comment: TFS won't change anything to your solution, you need to check if you get project om another machine, is the project working?

Answer (score 0):

I have this error often. Just clean your solution in the `build -> Clean` option.

Comment: @user3302358 Does the path for the metadata files point to your bin directory?

Comment: @user3302358 The files the errors point to should be .dll files with the same names as your projects dependencies. Copy these dll's to the same directory where the errors are searching (the `bin\debug` directory)

Comment: Yes, but i no have generated this .dll files. How can I get this dll files?

Comment: @user3302358 Please can you go to your Project in Visual Studio, and click on the `References` dropdown. Then tell me if the unfound files are there.

Comment: No i can't found this file.

Comment: @user3302358 Please can you post a screenshot of your errors, with the References dropdown clearly visible.

Comment: @user3302358 Thank you for posting your image, and I have answered your question. However, please edit your original question to include the image, and delete your answer with the image in.

Answer (score 0):

Your project is malformed, due to the fact that it's pointing to unusual paths. I'm afraid you need to recreate your project with a better layout. A logical solution leads to a simple and logical application. If you wish I will help you get set up with a clean and simple project layout, and get you on your way.

Comment: I know but other people have downloaded this project from tfs and its work for his.

Comment: other than checking the version history and see if anyone has changed the core files, I don't know what the solution could be. But I highly recommend cleaning your solution and ensuring it's easy to find your way around.